# How do you convert a string into a float or a integer in Ada?

Tags: ada, typeconverter

i'm supposed to dive a Float with a String and the sum is suposed to be an integer.

procedure Kvoten_Av(Flyt: in Float;
Str: in String;
Kvot: out Integer) is

begin

```
  Kvot:= Integer(Flyt / Float(Str));
```

end Kvoten_Av;

This obviously doesnt work but it was my first guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ada 2012 Reference Manual section K.2 contains the following description of the

> 'Value attribute: S'Value For every scalar subtype S:    S'Value
> denotes a function with the following specification:
> function S'Value(Arg : String) return S'Base
>
> This function returns a value given an image of the value as a String,
> ignoring any leading or trailing spaces.

If a string named str contains a string representation of a number it can be converted to a float value with the following syntax:

```ada
My_Float_Number : float;
...
My_Float_Number := float'Value(str);
```

Scalar subtypes include floating point types, signed or unsigned integer types, modular types and enumeration types.

Comment: Related examples using `Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get` are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63864845/230513).